# How to add aws ssl certificate on tomcat on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I have got SSL certificate on AWS on ELB. How should I add the certificate in tomcat? I can't find any proper guidance.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html)

> You cannot directly install ACM certificates on your Amazon Elastic
>   Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) website or application. You can, however,
>   use your certificate with any integrated service. For more
>   information, see [Services Integrated with AWS Certificate
>   Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html).

Comment: I have got the certificate on AWS itself and applied it via ELB. But I don't know how to set that certificate in tomcat, any guide about that?

Comment: @ImaMiri You don't need to setup certificate in tomcat. run tomcat in http and configure ELB to serve it as https.